# After cancelling the purchase made by google play billing processing the purchase query shows purchase state as 1 in the loop

Tags: android, in-app-billing, google-play-billing

I have purchased and cancelled the order. So it got refunded. After the refund the purchaseState is in 0 (UNSPECIFIED_STATE). Hereafter cancellation of the purchaseQuerySkus return the state as 0.

But the for loop returns the value as 1 for getPurchaseState.

But while processing it satisfying the condition. It is weird.

```
List returns for me [Purchase.Json: {
        "orderId": "orderID",
        "packageName": "com.android.app",
        "productId": "in_app",
        "purchaseTime": 29323923232,
        "purchaseState": 0,
        "purchaseToken": "weorehrhjewrhewirhewiruhewfbewfbweuyfbwehfbweyfbwefbwefweuyfhweyufhwe",
        "quantity": 1,
        "acknowledged": true
    }]
```

Code:

```
     private List<Purchase> purchaseQuerySkus;
    
    private void queryPurchasesAsync() {
            if(mBillingClient.isReady()) {
                LogUtils.LOGI(TAG, "queryPurchasesAsync");
                billingClient.queryPurchasesAsync(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP, new PurchasesResponseListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onQueryPurchasesResponse(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult, @NonNull List<Purchase> list) {
                        LogUtils.LOGI(TAG, "queryPurchasesAsync list" + list);
                        purchaseQuerySkus = list;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    
    Checking the purchase is already made or not after the cancellation. It returning the purchaseState as 0. But the print values shows as 1.
    
     if (billingClient.isReady()) {
                    queryPurchasesAsync();
                    LogUtils.LOGI(TAG, "QUE_PUR_LIST_SIZE " + purchaseQuerySkus.size()); 
                    //It returns the size of the list as 1
       
                    for (Purchase pur : purchaseQuerySkus) {
                        String thisSku = pur.getSkus().get(0); //my sku value
                        LogUtils.LOGI(TAG, "pur.getPurchase state " + pur.getPurchaseState()); //It prints the value as 1 
But the returned list has the purchaseState as 0 which I have added above.
                        // So it satisfying the condition and showing the item was purchased
                        if (pur.getPurchaseState() == Purchase.PurchaseState.PURCHASED) {
                       // Acknowledging the user if purchased
    
                     }
```

Comment: How have u worked around it?

Answer (score 5):

I know I'm a bit late for the party but stil... This also surprised me. It's because list is using `toString()` to show elements which in turns uses original json and `purchaseState` from json isn't directly matched with `Purchase.PurchaseState` enum. If you checkout `Purchase.class` file there you'll find this enum:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
    public @interface PurchaseState {
        int UNSPECIFIED_STATE = 0;
        int PURCHASED = 1;
        int PENDING = 2;
}
```

and if you check `Purchase.getPurchaseState()` you'll see how it's converting purchaseState from json int to `Purchase.PurchaseState` enum. Please note that by default it's picking purchased state and it looks like `Purchase.PurchaseState.UNSPECIFIED_STATE` from java class is never used.

```
public int getPurchaseState() {
        switch(this.zzc.optInt("purchaseState", 1)) {
        case 4:
            return 2;
        default:
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have u found any solution?